# Can you test for a null password?

Tags: password, authentication

I have users who authenticate using Twitter and Facebook (using the Social Login add-on). Those users have no password.

Is this something I can test for using ExpressionEngine logic?

The obvious suspects don't seem to work, but it's not terribly surprising:

```
{if password != ""}password == yes{/if}
{if password}password == yes{/if}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From their [**Docs**](http://www.intoeetive.com/docs/social_login.html#userdata):

> The contents of {password_block} is displayed only when password is
>   empty.

So `{password_block} password == no{/password_block}` should do the trick inside the `exp:social_login:add_userdata` tag.

Comment: Nice! I looked but didn't find it, thanks :)